# Emacs doesn't detect octave (windows)

Tags: octave

I am new to Emacs and trying to set up octave so that it runs inside Emacs. I followed the instructions on the official website but it didn't work as Emacs threw a error

`searching for program: no such file or directory, octave`

Following the directions given on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796606/octave-in-emacs-searching-for-program-so-such-file-or-directory) in stack overflow, I added octave in environment variables and the commandline launches octave without any issues but the problem on Emacs persisted.

I tried the solution given on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187956/how-to-run-octave-in-emacs) but the problem persists.

My `init.el` file looks like this

```
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq inferior-octave-program "C:/Octave/Octave-5.1.0.0/octave.vbs")
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (abbrev-mode 1)
            (auto-fill-mode 1)
            (if (eq window-system 'x)
                (font-lock-mode 1))))

(autoload 'run-octave "octave-inf" nil t)
```

And the error message is

`searching for program: no such file or directory, C:/Octave/Octave-5.1.0.0/octave.vbs`

Comment: `octave-mode` comes preconfigured with Emacs, so the first line above is redundant (and even harmful because `octave-mod.el` has been renamed in "recent" Emacsen).